# Equating sides and solving sides for Similar Triangles

Tags: geometry

[image: I can't do geometry, send help]

It looks simple but for some reason I can't get it out. After equating sides of the triangles using the common side AY from the similarity, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

By similarity, $ BC= \frac{AB}{AX} XY$

and $AD= \frac{AB}{BX} XY$

Now take their reciprocals and add using $AB = AX + BX$ to get the desired result

Comment: I agree with BC=(AB)/(AX) * XY, but there are no similar triangles that directly relate (AD)/(XY)

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw it! Thanks for the help!